# Best code to generate 1,000,000 files from Database

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

Using C#, I want to generate 1,000,000 files from DB, each record in separate file.
What is the best way to generate this files in minimum time?

Here is my code without threading :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit); // to calculate the execution time in case of using threading
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1000000 p1+','+p2+','+p3+','+p4 as line from lines  ", con);

    con.Open();
    var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 0;
    while (rdr.Read())
    {

        string line = rdr.Getring(0);
        string filename = String.Format("file{0}.txt", ++i);
        File.WriteAllText(filename, line);

    }
    rdr.Close();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: He would have to be becuase of the var keyword in his code.

Comment: Do you really want them all in one directory?

Comment: (1) Windows Explorer can't deal with thousands of files in one directory. NTFS can, though. Prepare to work via the command line, or programmatically. Consider splitting the files to subfolders. (2) If the filenames end up longer than the DOS 8.3, NTFS will create a short name for you. That will slow to a crawl with 100,000's files. Disable short names. (3) If not subfolders, consider naming the files in a way that lets you work on them in groups. e.g. f0000001.txt, instead of f1.txt. http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=57616

Comment: I use NTFS and i'll not use explorer to view the files
all files names will be from 000001.txt to 999999.txt all in single folder

Comment: If this is more than a 1-off thing, you might be better to look at using some of the concepts in Jeffrey Richter’s Power Threading Library http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546608.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your operations are IO bound and not CPU bound, the best way is to have 2 threads, one that reads from DB the records and put it into a queue, the other read from the queue and generate the files.

Alternatively, you can use the CLR thread pool for that, something like

```
while (rdr.Read())
    {

        string line = rdr.Getring(0);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (new WaitCallback(writeData), line);

    }
```

and writeData would look like

```
static void writeData(Object line)
{
            string filename = String.Format("file{0}.txt", ++i);
            File.WriteAllText(filename, line);
}
```

The disadvantage of using the ThreadPool is you could end up more threads than you want,  since your threads will be blocked in IO most of the time, the thread pool will create new threads to service your requests.

You can try the thread pool first and measure the performance, if you are  not satisfied, you can try the 2 threads, 1 queue approach; well known as Producer/Consumer problem.

Comment: Using thread pool generates only 2713 files and exit my application.

unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit from having more threads; the best way to figure out the exact number is empirically, but don't limit yourself to one per CPU core the way you might with CPU-bound tasks.  The very easiest way is to use a ThreadPool, but a Producer/Consumer queuing system would be more flexible and tunable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SSIS package? Isn't it supposed to do these kind of things?

Comment: Do you have any article about SSIS package to generate files?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/12/04/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Splitting-a-file-into-multiple-files.aspx) might help.

Comment: this works great if your database is only SQL Server:) I hope the majority of people are using:)

Comment: Although he has not shown the connection string, use of SQLCommand suggests he is using SQL as database. Hence I guess this can be used.

Comment: Yes , I use SQLserver 2008 , and I can't find a way to generate each record into a single file using SSIS,
Can any one help?

Comment: If I use only the script task in SSIS ,is this equivalent to write a code in c# , or it will be better in performance?